# How Eliminate ? in this string with preg_mach

Tags: php, regex

Hello Have this string

```
class="_2zACE" href="/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true"
```

I Use this Regx

```
preg_match_all('/class="_2zACE" href="(\/tv-shows\/)(.+?)\/(.+?)?start=true"/',$url_pre_series,$url_lote_serie,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The Anwser is this:

```
Array
(
   
    [0] => class="_2zACE" href="/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true"
    
    [1] => /tv-shows/
    
    [2] => 521987
    
    [3] => s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?

)
```

How I can do for eliminate the last `?` in the Array [3], i try difference option but nothing.

Comment: If your regex is perfect, you can just use trim() on string at 3rd index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the questionmark outside of the capturing group and as it was part of the previous group which was optional, you could make the question mark itself optional using `\??`

To match the parts in between, you could also use 2 negated character classes if you want to match 2 parts

```
class="_2zACE" href="(\/tv-shows\/)([^/]*)\/([^/?]*)?\??start=true
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RH0u4v/1)

If you change the delimiter from `/` to for example `~` you don't have to escape the backslash.

```
$url_pre_series = 'class="_2zACE" href="/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true"';
preg_match_all('~class="_2zACE" href="(\/tv-shows\/)([^/]*)\/([^/?]*)?\??start=true~',$url_pre_series,$url_lote_serie,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($url_lote_serie);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => class="_2zACE" href="/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true
            [1] => /tv-shows/
            [2] => 521987
            [3] => s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specific tools to [manipulate HTML](https://php.net/domdocument) and [parse URLs](https://php.net/parse_url), which are normally easier to use and more reliable than regular expressions:

```
$html = '<a class="_2zACE" href="/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true">Blah</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$url = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->getAttribute('href');
$parsed = parse_url($url);
var_dump($url, $parsed['path']);
```

```
string(65) "/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift?start=true"
string(54) "/tv-shows/521987/s01_e01_the_killings_at_badgers_drift"
```

(This is just a quick [demo](https://3v4l.org/nGiKe), please tweak to your liking).